Odds Ratio in a Logistic Model
I have fitted a logistic regression model in R and I've obtained an accuracy of 95%, an AUC score of 0.98, a brier score of 0.4 with sensitivity and specificity values around 90%, so I would call it a good model, and i'm sure i'm not overfitting it because the sample size is big enough, i used a nested cross validation for the training and previous works with this dataset have similar metric scores. But when i evaluate the Odds Ratio by using
# Tidy model for Odds Ratio
OR_forward <- tidy(model_forward, conf.int = TRUE, exp = TRUE)
# View
print(OR_forward)

of the model i obtain
| term                 |    estimate     | std.error        | statistic        | p.value        | conf.low        | conf.high        |
| -------------------- | --------------- | ---------------- | ---------------- | -------------- | --------------- | ---------------- |
| (Intercept)          | 0.9803722       | 0.5585423        | -0.0354905       | 0.9716886222   | 0.34167844      | 3.099333e+00     |
| perimeter_worst      | 138.4584082     | 1.6246777        | 3.0347988        | 0.0024069620   | 8.85712651      | 6.073470e+03     |
| smoothness_worst     | 2.8558969       | 0.6659321        | 1.5758153        | 0.1150683769   | 0.86645297      | 1.232178e+01     |
| texture_worst        | 21.1155988      | 0.8005182        | 3.8100470        | 0.0001389404   | 5.43421791      | 1.362067e+02     |
| radius_se            | 249.6495402     | 1.7514729        | 3.1516663        | 0.0016234171   | 18.82154660     | 1.576302e+04     |
| concave.points_worst | 12.5199362      | 1.3407680        | 1.8849810        | 0.0594324041   | 1.06768453      | 2.285697e+02     |
| fractal_dimension_se | 0.1506027       | 0.6689871        | -2.8298153       | 0.0046574880   | 0.03406688      | 4.961252e-01     |
| concavity_mean       | 13.0852042      | 1.1904412        | 2.1601084        | 0.0307642776   | 1.28731054      | 1.542539e+02     |
| texture_se           | 0.1935264       | 0.8072612        | -2.0344610       | 0.0419051325   | 0.03440948      | 8.765000e-01     |

which is strange to me. The only action I did with my data was scaling them by using
data[-1] <- scale(data[-1]) # The first column is categorical

I also plotted the residuals
plot(residuals(model_forward)) #stats library


because from what i understood outliers may impact the OR of the model, but i presume i cant simply remove them from the data. Can anyone help me understand why my OR are so high and lower them or how should i interpret those values?

Why do you think the ORs shouldn't be that high? We as outsiders not knowing the meaning of the data can't say whether these are realistic or not. And indeed don't "simply remove outliers" unless you have a clear indication that something went wrong with them. Also it'd be helpful to know with what command exactly you produced plot and table, as there are various versions of residuals around in such models, and we can't comment on something as long as we don't know exactly what it is.

I thought that ORs with such big values shouldn't be correct because a single feature being able to impact that much an outcome seemed impossible to me. I have little to no experience with ORs so i'm still trying to learn how to deal with this metric. I also updated the question by specifing the command used

Have you checked for colinearity? Also, some of your variables sound like they are categorized versions of continuous variables (the ones with _worst) that's not usually a good method.
Also, you say your sample is "big enough" but you have a lot of variables, are some of the cells very small?

Yes i checked VIF values for my model and they were all under a value of 5, which is the critical threshold if i understood properly. Regarding the variables, i am using the Wisconsin  Breast Cancer Classification dataset which comes with 10 continuos variables with mean, worst and SE so i cant really do anything about that. Finally about sample size i used the pmsampsize function to check whether i had enough samples in my dataset, which was confirmed (360 needed, 569 provided)

"I thought that ORs with such big values shouldn't be correct because a single feature being able to impact that much an outcome seemed impossible to me". How do you interpret the odds ratios you see in this model, exactly? e.g. what does an OR of 138 for the "perimeter_worst" variable mean to you?

It should mean that an increase of one unit of "perimeter_worst" would increase around 138 times the odds of the event of interest, which seems a lot. On the other hand, my data are now scaled so the range of perimeter_worst is [-1.6, 4.2] so an increment of a unit may have an important difference, but i'm not really sure about it

I'm not sure what you think the problem is. Large (and small) odds ratios imply that the predictors strongly predict the outcome (conditional on the other predictors in the model). That is consistent with your finding that the model has strong predictive accuracy. There is no contradiction and nothing to be that concerned with. I would say that with a small-ish sample (<1000) and very strong predictors, you might look into using regularized logistic regression (e.g., ridge or lasso), especially since it looks like you selected this model using forward selection, which is among the worst variable selection methods, or Firth logistic regression, which reduces the bias in logistic regression coefficients while retaining the ability for asymptotic inference.
If you could be clearer about what you think the problem is and why you think it's a problem, we might be able to give you better answers. From what you posted, it is unclear what you think the problem is (large odds ratios?) or why you think that's a problem (it "looks strange"?).

Yes I used the forward selection algorithm because it is what the teacher told me to use but i also used a lasso model in order to compare the two models, but by plotting the ORs of the lasso model i still have big values (>100). Additionally, by plotting the VIF values i found that the lasso model has huge collinearity (many predictos have VIF values over 20) so i used an algorithm that iteratively deleted the predictors with vif values over 5, but i still remained with a model with ORs over 50. My problem is that having ORs with such big values seems wrong, but i might be mistaken about it

@Leo_Miche the VIF doesn't matter for making predictions. HIgh VIF increases the standard errors of coefficient estimates, but those are typically offset by covariances among the estimates when making predictions via the weighted sum of correlated variables that combines predictor values with coefficients. High OR just means that the predictor performs very well; cancer cells look a lot different from benign cells. You might want to test overfitting directly by resampling instead of relying on the number of cases, however.

One way to understand your OR is to look at the bivariate association of the variable with a huge OR and your dependent variable. A simple crosstabulation may show that perimeter_worst simply does strongly predict your outcome.
